# Numpy printing with iterator .format throws an error

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, iterator, formatting, jupyter-notebook

Using anaconda distribution, Python 3.61 and using Jupyter notebook for Scipy/Numpy. I can use the print(' blah {} '.format(x)) to format numbers but if I iterate over a nparray I get an error.

```
# test of formatting
'{:+f}; {:+f}'.format(3.14, -3.14)  # show it always
```

example stolen from the Python 3.6 manual section 6.1.3.2 [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) and I get the expected response. So I know that it isn't that I've forgotten to import something i.e. it is built in.

if I do this:

```
C_sense = C_pixel + C_stray
print('Capacitance of node')
for x, y in np.nditer([Names,C_sense]):
    print('The  {} has C ={} [F]'.format(x,y))
```

I get output

```
Capacitance of node
The  551/751 has C =8.339999999999999e-14 [F]
The  554     has C =3.036e-13 [F]
The  511     has C =1.0376e-12 [F]
```

But if I do this:

```
# now with formatting
C_sense = C_pixel + C_stray
print('Capacitance of node')
for x, y in np.nditer([Names,C_sense]):
    print('The  {} has C ={:.3f} [F]'.format(x,y))
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-321e0b5edb03> in <module>()
      3 print('Capacitance of node')
      4 for x, y in np.nditer([Names,C_sense]):
----> 5     print('The  {} has C ={:.3f} [F]'.format(x,y))

TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__
```

I've attached a screen shot of my Jupyter notebook to show context of this code.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is clearly coming from the formatter, not knowing what to do with the numpy iterable you get from `np.nditer`.

Does the following work?

```
for x,y in zip(Names,C_sense):
    print('The  {} has C ={:.3f} [F]'.format(x,y))
```

Comment: You could also try giving the formatting function a more friendly type by casting to a float with `float(y)`.

Comment: Your suggestion of zip does indeed work.!  I've +1 but will hang off on the answer acceptance for a while. Nice.

Comment: As does the casting. Which doesn't make sense to me as the nparray is of type float. I guess I don't have a complete picture of what is happening in Numpy. Thanks again.